# My Vs code is unable to connect to my android and ios simulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried adding a google font plugin in in my `pubspec.yaml` file, but it is giving me the following error message.

```
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-6.2.0/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:69:8: Error: Type 'FontFeature' not found.
google_fonts_base.dart:69
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Plus.
Exited
```

Comment: Add your `flutter doctor -v` results too.

Comment: can you try  `google_fonts: ^6.2.1`

Comment: Thank you @FpB. I’ve tried that but no issue found

Comment: Thank you @Md.YeasinSheikh. This is the same plug in I used before the issue started.

Comment: try with cache repair`flutter pub cache repair `

Answer (score 0):

The newest update of google_font: ^6.2.0 is causing the issue with

Use this cmd to solve it: `flutter pub downgrade google_fonts`